# im trying to randomly generate some objects in unity 2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i am trying to generate some islands in a 2d game in unity using this code:

```
public class terraingen : MonoBehaviour

    {
        int generate = 10;
        public int distance = 5;
        int i;
        void Start()
        {
            for (i = 1; i <= generate; i++)
            {
                float x = transform.position.x;
                float a = x + distance;
                transform.position = new Vector3(a, 2, 0);
                Instantiate(gameObject);
            }
        }
    }
```

now the problem is when i enter play mode because it doesnt load, i mean it only shows "Hold up(busy for mins:sec)" and the time it is "busy" never ends.
i tried using other codes from the internet but none worked, some had the same result and others just didnt work

Comment: How do you know that it didn't work?  You may be putting the island right on top of each other so it looks like no new islands were created.  the position is in pixels and 5 pixels is very small.

Comment: because it wont load, thats my problem, it just crashes unity when i enter playmode

Comment: Yes you are recursively generating objects of course unity crashes. You have a Start that spawns other objects that you're spawning. Make the gameObject you are spawning a different object or make the spawner a different object. To explain very straight forward,  everytime you spawn a new objects it spawns new objects and they spawn new objects, etc. until crash. If you need to be clarify I can type up a working snippet.

Comment: oh didnt think of that, it makes sense thanks